# How do I call the soap service in Java?

Tags: java, http, soap, asmx

I would like to call the soap service that I have implemented externally in Java.

However, the following error will continue to occur.
'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction'

Please see what's wrong with my code.

test url is 'http://example.com/test.asmx?op=tt'

** what is soapaction?????

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

  // SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
  public static void main (String args[]) {

   String soapEndpointUrl = "http://example.com/test.asmx" ;
     String soapAction = "http://example.com/tt" ;

    callSoapWebService (soapEndpointUrl , soapAction ) ;
  }

private static void createSoapEnvelope (SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws SOAPException {
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage .getSOAPPart () ;

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope .getBody () ;
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBody .addChildElement ( "element1") ;
    soapBodyElem11 .addTextNode ( "test") ;
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBody .addChildElement ( "element2") ;
    soapBodyElem12 .addTextNode ( "test") ;

}

private static void callSoapWebService (String soapEndpointUrl, String soapAction ) {
    try {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory . newInstance() ;
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory .createConnection () ;

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection .call ( createSOAPRequest( soapAction ), soapEndpointUrl) ;

        // Print the SOAP Response
        System .out . println( "Response SOAP Message:" );
        soapResponse .writeTo ( System. out );
        System .out . println() ;

        soapConnection .close () ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System .err . println( "\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n") ;
        e .printStackTrace () ;
    }
}

  private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest (String soapAction) throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory .newInstance () ;
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory .createMessage () ;

    createSoapEnvelope (soapMessage ) ;

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage .getMimeHeaders () ;
    headers .addHeader ( "SOAPAction", soapAction) ;

    soapMessage .saveChanges () ;

    /* Print the request message, just for debugging purposes */
    System .out . println( "Request SOAP Message:" );
    soapMessage .writeTo ( System. out );
    System .out . println( "\n" );

    return soapMessage ;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there no WSDL available? It would be much easier because you can generate a client using eclipse or wsimport.